# Parsing data from one sheet to many others

Tags: excel

There is one sheet, where all data is listed and there are over 9,000 other sheets that reference to that one and take some of that data.

What I have to do manually now: In every single one of that many, I should write formula in certain cell, that references to our "Data-sheet" and takes certain data. Cell is exactly the same in all sheets. The formula looks like this:

```
=ListOfData!A1
```

and for second sheet it looks like:

```
=ListOfData!A2
```

...and so forth and so on.

Can I write those formulas in all of the sheets without hardcoding?

Comment: You have a workbook with 9000 sheets??

Comment: Unfortunatelly, yes, I do have so many sheets. And I can't dig into VBA now, just haven't time for that.

Comment: How do you even select the sheet you want O.o And how much memory do you have?

Comment: "...I can't dig into VBA now, just don't have time for that." Understood, but I really think you should make time. If you're routinely dealing with over 50 spreadsheets (much less *over 9000!*) learning VBA will reduce your manual workload a *ton*.  As you have it now, you don't have time for VBA, because part of that time is going to be pasting a formula, manually, to thousands of pages!  Instead, perhaps think of using that time to learn some quick VBA, then you can automate this process. (Edit: Ah, actually you could probably do a quick Find/Replace on Formulas to switch this).

Comment: That's really uncomfortable, but it is work documentation, so I have to do it somehow :) about memory: just 4gb RAM, but I almost sure, that some of new sheets, that I opened when passing by, loads in memory and others that I'm already opened disappear from there. Something like that...

Comment: So basically, you need to enter `=ListofData!A[SheetNumber]` in some cell, in every sheet except `ListofData`?  What cell will that reference go in in each of the sheets?

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you for advice, really. But it is not my routin, friend of mine asked me for solving this problem and I agreed (damn it!)'

Comment: @BruceWayne Cell, when I should paste data is C14 (in all sheets for pasting data) and column in ListOfData, when that list of data is located is E

Comment: If the 9000 sheets have some kind of naming convention, and the workbook is a saved document, then one could use `CELL("filename",A1)` to get at the name of the sheet.  From there you could create a formula to calculate the index based on the name, and use `Indirect` to reference the original ListOfData.  But is it true that there is a naming convention?  And that the workbook is currently saved?

Comment: @Demetri Thanks, that was good thought, but I already did it the way BruceWayne helps me below. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're needing, here's a quick macro I did for you:

```
Sub addFormula()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "ListofData" Then
        With ws
            'This places the formula in cell A1 of each sheet. Change as necessary!
            .Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=ListOfData!A" & ws.Index
        End With
    End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Place that in the Workbook module.  What it will do is use the Sheet Index to determine the formula (i.e. the second sheet in the index will have `=ListofData!A2` in Cell `A1`.

To change where your formula goes, edit the `.Cells(1,1)` to fix that (format is `.Cells([Row],[Column])`.

Since you have *over 9000* sheets, I am hoping to all the gods that their indexes are the same number you want.  If not, you'll need to specify how we know which sheet gets `A1`, `A2`,...,`A9000` in the formula.

I **highly** suggest trying this in a copy of the workbook, with say 40 sheets before using this on the large one.

Comment: I will try do it now and anyway that's awesome. I take off my hat, sir. I'll accept answer if it's right, as soon as possible. Otherwise, I'll write a comment here for you :)

Comment: @A.But - Yeah, let me know. With over 9000 sheets, I hesitate to say the above will work as it (but there's always a chance!).  See Demetri's comment - is there some naming convention we could use instead?

Comment: Aaand... that was the right answer. Thank you one more time, you are great! :D

Comment: About naming convention: there is one, but problem is solved, so we can don't care about it

Comment: Almost forgot, there was one single little mistake. Indicies of "parsed" sheets starts not from 1, but from 2, because first sheet is ListOfData itself :) I just added `-1` to the end and here we go

Comment: @A.But - Happy to help! Just a note though: Unless you have some way to check all 9000 formulas, we may want to use the naming convention.  Just because the macro above assumes that *each and every sheet's index is correct.  Edit: Ah! You caught it and made an adjustment I see, nicely done.  My final comment is to set aside some time to learn VBA, as you can see it can **greatly** increase your efficiency.